# why the ffmpeg cuda decoder much slower than the cpu decoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

```
# cpu
ffmpeg -i test.ts -f null /dev/null -benchmark
# gpu
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -c:v h264_cuvid -i test.ts -f null /dev/null -benchmark
```

ffmpeg  4.4.2

the CPU is 1.5x faster than the GPU one.

Why is that I actually expect the GPU one will be way faster?

Please noticed, in this pipeline I do not even do any encoding at all.

Comment: What's your CPU and what's your GPU?

Comment: @Wang I think you are right - the GPU decoding seems slower than expected in my machine too. When asking a question related to benchmarking, we have to make sure that the results are reproducible. Start by defining an input video file, example: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1920x1080:rate=1:duration=10000 -c:v h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4`. Add details about the CPU, the GPU, the OS, other related stuff like disk drive, memory type (like DDR4...), PCIe configuration, NVIDIA driver... Also please add the results of the benchmarking.

Answer (score -1):

`-c:v h264_cuvid` is calling CUVID, which is slower and less efficient than NVENC. Replace it it with `-c:v h264_nvenc`

CUVID for encode and decode is decades old and should be considered depreciated. It lights up all of the CUDA cores of the GPU to perform the functionality. The behavior likely desired is to invoke NVENC or NVDEC which are both faster and dramatically more power efficient for both video encoding and video decoding.

There are useful ways to use CUDA to accelerate video encoding tasks with FFmpeg, see NVIDIA's examples here: https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/11.1/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/index.html

Also see FFmpeg's documentation on how to appropriately call modern NVENC/NVDEC: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#NVDECCUVID

Comment: nvenc is for encoding not decoding

Comment: for decoding it is always cuvid, try `ffmpeg -decoders | grep -i nvidia` you will see what I meant

Comment: `-c:v h264_cuvid` in your posted question is specifically calling CUVID as an encoder is the most likely cause of your slow down, or, at the least, a contributing factor.

Comment: I updated the answer with additional documentation hopefully to provide clarity. I believe you may be misunderstanding what your FFmpeg commands are requesting.